# Дублирование товаров в uc3

Tags: drupal

помогите пожалуйста разобраться

использую ubercart3. сразу после установки создаю один товар и вывожу его через встроенные представления uc_catalog и uc_catalog_term. в результатетовар выводится в контентной части несколько раз. вот [скриншот](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/tt.png)

соответственно если создаю несколько товаров(ручками или при попощи devel), то они тоже дублируются. в среднем по 2-4 раза

помогите пожалуйста избавиться от дублирования и понять почему оно происходит